# How can I uniquely identify a lambda (may be capturing) contained within a std::function in C++

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, lambda

I planned to use a set-like container (for example `QSet` in qt or `std::set`) to hold `std::function` objects wrapping lambda (capturing or non-capturing) to avoid adding the same lambda multiple times. And these classess all require users providing comparing or hash calculation functions for key type.

However as long as I know, if the underlying lambda is capturing, the `target()` method returns `nullptr` and thus two `std::function`s cannot be compared based on return values of it.

So how can I compare two arbitrary `std::function`s, or at least calculate a unique value from a `std::function`?

Comment: `std::set<std::pair<std::type_index, std::function<..>>, CompareFirst>`?

Comment: Use `std::function<R(Args...)>::target_type`?

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you, ````std::type_index```` is exactly what I want. It feels really good to learn some new C++ every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every lambda has its own unique type, so you could use target_type for your purpose. Only non-capturing lambdas are convertible to function ptrs.
Note that it is not trivial to compare whether two functions are equal, depending on what equal is in your context.
If you have multiple parts in your code where you define the "same" lambda it still might have a different type.

```
auto l1 = [](){};
auto l2 = [](){};
```

l1 and l2 have different types and would create different entries in your set.